# Word or idiom for the "traditional" charade without ambiguity?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, ambiguity

From the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charades), a *charade* is

> A word guessing game [...] in which one player acts out a word or phrase, often by miming similar-sounding words, and the other players guess the word or phrase.

The previous definition is the most recent one, but traditionally a charade was :

> A riddle either in verse or prose, of which the listener must guess the meaning, often given syllable by syllable

For example :

> My first is a preposition (for)
>   My next a composition (tune)
>   My whole is an acquisition (fortune).

Is there a word/group of words in English that means the "traditional charade" without ambiguity and without defining the whole game ?

(Note that in French the word *charade* only refers to the traditional version of the game)

Comment: I think, today, we simply call these "riddles", but of course there are more kinds of riddles than just these charades.

Comment: @DanBron I know "riddles" but I think it is too broad, I am looking for a more specific word

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but I think today there is no more specific word, and anyone person-on-the-street you asked to name this game would call it simply a "puzzle". I don't think anyone (here in the US at least) is familiar with this earlier sense of "charades" (as a game).

Comment: If you used pictures for each syllable, it would be a [rebus](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rebus)

Comment: "Charade" (when not used metaphorically) has meant a party game for at least 60 years.  I think most people would consider this the "traditional" meaning.  The party game meaning was well-established by the time of the 1963 movie [Charade](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056923/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).

Comment: The game is *charades* (plural). A *charade* (singular) is a *farce*. Like others, I too doubt anyone today is familiar with the earlier version of the game (apparently called *charade*) and would recognize it under *any* name.

Comment: @michael.hor257k It is very well known in France and (almost) anybody knows what it is. I was just wondering if there is a word in English, but it seems that there is not?

Comment: @Lordofdark The word in English is *charade*. It is [listed](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/charade) as such in the Oxford dictionary - and AFAICT in no other.

Answer (score 1):

**conundrum**

> a riddle, the answer to which involves a pun or play on words, as *What
>   is black and white and read all over? A newspaper*.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/conundrum

Comment: Sorry it's not what I am looking for